# Where can I find android folder in React Native 0.46.4

Tags: android, react-native, npm

I'm trying to install several `RN libraries`.
Some of them are demand to write code manually in android gradle file or else.

In older version of `React Native project`, there are `android` and `ios` folder of project root, but in my case I can't find them.

I want to write code on

```
'android/app/build.gradle'
'android/settings.gradle'
'MainActivity'.
```

**Q:** Where can I find those files?

Comment: How did you create your project? If the folders aren't there, then my guess is that you used the `create-react-native-app` in which case you need to [eject](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/README.md#ejecting-from-create-react-native-app) to work with any 3rd party modules that need linking. Also, read everything about `eject` to understand what it does and when to do it. It's not reversible.

Comment: are you using expo ?

Comment: Yeah I'm using expo

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using Expo, you'll have to [detach](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html#content) (the [instructions](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html#1-install-exp) are very straightforward). It has the same side effects as [eject](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/README.md#ejecting-from-create-react-native-app) for `create-react-native-app`. Once detached, you will have the `android` and `ios` folders in your project's root directory like a normal `react-native init` project.

You should read through everything explained on that page as **this is a non-reversible action**. Once detached, you will lose some benefits exclusive to an Expo project such as [Push Notifications](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications.html#content) through Expo's servers.